# Locate tables after appendix

Tags: tables, appendices

I would like to include tables in appendix of my document. But latex persistently locate them spontaneously: some of tables before "Appendix" title and some after.
My aim is to force latex to locate all tables of appendix after "Appendix" title.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please rest assured that LaTeX does *nothing* spontaneously... Please tell us how you've set the positioning specifier of the very first `table` after the appendix header.

Comment: latex just follows the instructions in the document, if the instructions are wrong it will do the wrong thing, but it is hard to say what is wrong with the code if you do not show it. possibly you want to use `\suppressfloats[t]` on the first page of the appendix to stop top floats there.